# ListView - Details View: Does 'this' belong to 'this'?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

In Details View for the `ListView` `Control`, how can I do something like this, in the simplest way?

```
if(listView1.SelectedItem belongs to listView1.Groups["BaseballGroup"])
{
   MessageBox.Show("The selected item is inside the Baseball Group");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's no property `SelectedItem` but a list of `SelectedItems`, then:

```
if(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Group == listView1.Groups["BaseballGroup"])
{
   //...
}
```

**N.B.**
Check if something is selected (`SelectedItems.Count > 0`) to do `SelectedItems[0]` safely.

Comment: This'll be inside a SelectedIndex event, so I think it's pretty safe to assume something's selected, but yeah, thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try

listView1.Groups["BaseballGroup"].Contains(listView1.SelectedItem.ToString())